# section covering 100% height of the viewport

Tags: height, css

I made a lot of research on this site (and others) but I can't solve my problem…
On this website : http://vintagebike.fr/t%C3%A9t%C3%A9/ 
I want that each sections covers 100% of the height of the viewport…
I set up at min-height : 100% for eachs…
I set up html, body at height : 100%

some code :

```
html{ overflow-y:scroll; font-size:100%; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; line-height:1.5; background:url(...) repeat top left; font-color:#353232; height:100%;}



body{ height:100%; background:#fff; float:left; width:100%; font-size:.8125em; color:#353232;}

#about{background-color: #cde2f3;position:relative;min-height:100%;}
#elements{background-color: #fbe2e4;position:relative;min-height:100%;}
#pourqui{background-color: #ffedc1;position:relative;min-height:100%;}
#contact{background-color: #ddeee4;position:relative;min-height:100%;}
```

If I set the height in pixels it's working…

I really don't understand…

Thanks in advance.

(sorry for my english)

Comment: Can you please provider some code?

Comment: sorry. I have edited my first message…

Answer (score 0):

Read the specification of [percentage height](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property). It has nothing to do with the viewport. Since you have `body {height:100%}`, as BODY grows, it becomes the element used to represent 100%, not the viewport.

You need to set the section height using JavaScript based on the browser's viewport size.

Bonne chance.

> Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with
>   respect to the height of the generated box's **containing block**. If the
>   height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it
>   depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely
>   positioned, the value computes to 'auto'. A percentage height on the
>   root element is relative to the initial containing block. Note: For
>   absolutely positioned elements whose containing block is based on a
>   block-level element, the percentage is calculated with respect to the
>   height of the padding box of that element. This is a change from CSS1,
>   where the percentage was always calculated with respect to the content
>   box of the parent element.

Comment: hum… I'm not sure I understand your comment… take a look at http://dev.manifold.ws/test/ (found on an other post relative to 100% height) when I  resize the window the height of each section is adapted…
I still don't understand why it doesn't work on my site...

Comment: Wow, cool. The difference I see: no 'float:left' on BODY, and no 'overflow-y:scroll' on HTML.

Comment: … I just tryed to remove it but no result.

Comment: I think there is a more complex reason but I can't post the entire code here?

Comment: You should be able to edit your own question and post the code.